# Shared Preferences in my app doesn't work in Splash Screen

Tags: java, android

What I'm trying to do is to bypass every time downloading file for VPN list because it takes too much time to load. Here is my code

As you can see in code base url download server list from here http://www.vpngate.net/api/iphone/ but every time app open it try to download file again and again I just want call this from local storage not from app.

I uses this app source code can you please help me with this.

**Update**

> How to bypass downloading file and include into app

my **SplashActivity.java**

```
package com.baztro.ultravpn.activity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.baztro.ultravpn.util.NetworkState;
import com.androidnetworking.AndroidNetworking;
import com.androidnetworking.common.Priority;
import com.androidnetworking.error.ANError;
import com.androidnetworking.interfaces.DownloadListener;
import com.androidnetworking.interfaces.DownloadProgressListener;
import com.daimajia.numberprogressbar.NumberProgressBar;

import com.baztro.ultravpn.R;
import com.baztro.ultravpn.model.Server;
import com.baztro.ultravpn.util.PropertiesService;
import com.baztro.ultravpn.util.Stopwatch;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InterruptedIOException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private NumberProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView commentsText;
    private static boolean loadStatus = false;
    private Handler updateHandler;

    private final int LOAD_ERROR = 0;
    private final int DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 1;
    private final int PARSE_PROGRESS = 2;
    private final int LOADING_SUCCESS = 3;
    private final int SWITCH_TO_RESULT = 4;
    private final String BASE_URL = "http://www.vpngate.net/api/iphone/";
    private final String BASE_FILE_NAME = "vpngate.csv";
   private SharedPreferences sp;
   private SharedPreferences.Editor editor ;


    private boolean premiumStage = true;

    private int percentDownload = 0;
    private Stopwatch stopwatch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        sp = getSharedPreferences("splash-detail", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sp.edit();

//        if(sp.getBoolean("downloadComplete" == true))
//        {
//
//            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainSplashActivity.class);
//            startActivity(intent);
//        }


            if (NetworkState.isOnline()) {
                if (loadStatus) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, UserActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    loadStatus = true;

                }
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.network_error))
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.network_error_message))
                        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.ok),
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                        onBackPressed();
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }



            progressBar = (NumberProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.number_progress_bar);
            commentsText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.commentsText);

            if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("firstPremiumLoad", false))
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.loaderPremiumText)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            progressBar.setMax(100);

            updateHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case LOAD_ERROR: {
                            commentsText.setText(msg.arg2);
                            progressBar.setProgress(100);
                        } break;
                        case DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS: {
                            commentsText.setText(R.string.downloading_csv_text);
                            progressBar.setProgress(msg.arg2);

                        } break;
                        case PARSE_PROGRESS: {
                            commentsText.setText(R.string.parsing_csv_text);
                            progressBar.setProgress(msg.arg2);
                        } break;
                        case LOADING_SUCCESS: {
                            commentsText.setText(R.string.successfully_loaded);
                            progressBar.setProgress(100);
                            Message end = new Message();
                            end.arg1 = SWITCH_TO_RESULT;
                            updateHandler.sendMessageDelayed(end,500);
                        } break;
                        case SWITCH_TO_RESULT: {

                            if (PropertiesService.getConnectOnStart()) {
                                Server randomServer = getRandomServer();
                                if (randomServer != null) {
                                    newConnecting(randomServer, true, true);
                                } else {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, UserActivity.class));
                                }
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, UserActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            progressBar.setProgress(0);


        }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        downloadCSVFile(BASE_URL, BASE_FILE_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean useHomeButton() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean useMenu() {
        return false;
    }

    private void downloadCSVFile(String url, String fileName) {
        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        AndroidNetworking.download(url, getCacheDir().getPath(), fileName)
                .setTag("downloadCSV")
                .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
                .setOkHttpClient(okHttpClient)
                .build()
                .setDownloadProgressListener(new DownloadProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long bytesDownloaded, long totalBytes) {
                        if(totalBytes <= 0) {
                            // when we dont know the file size, assume it is 1200000 bytes :)
                            totalBytes = 1200000;
                        }


                            percentDownload = (int)((100 * bytesDownloaded) / totalBytes);


                        Message msg = new Message();
                        msg.arg1 = DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS;
                        msg.arg2 = percentDownload;
                        updateHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    }
                })
                .startDownload(new DownloadListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDownloadComplete() {
                        editor.putBoolean("downloadComplete", true);
                        editor.apply();
                        parseCSVFile(BASE_FILE_NAME);


                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                        editor.putBoolean("downloadCompleteNo", false);
                        editor.apply();
                        Message msg = new Message();
                        msg.arg1 = LOAD_ERROR;
                        msg.arg2 = R.string.network_error;
                        updateHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                    }
                });
    }

    private void parseCSVFile(String fileName) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getCacheDir().getPath().concat("/").concat(fileName)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.arg1 = LOAD_ERROR;
            msg.arg2 = R.string.csv_file_error;
            updateHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                int startLine = 2;
                int type = 0;


                    dbHelper.clearTable();


                int counter = 0;
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (counter >= startLine) {
                        dbHelper.putLine(line, type);
                    }
                    counter++;

                }

                    Message end = new Message();
                    end.arg1 = LOADING_SUCCESS;
                    updateHandler.sendMessageDelayed(end,200);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.arg1 = LOAD_ERROR;
                msg.arg2 = R.string.csv_file_error_parsing;
                updateHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I commented **if** condition because it crashes app

Created a file **MainSplashActivity**

```
package com.baztro.ultravpn.activity;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.baztro.ultravpn.R;

public class MainSplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_splash);
    }
}
```

Comment: You if-statement is wrong. You have: `if(sp.getBoolean("downloadComplete" == true))` and instead you should have: `if(sp.getBoolean("downloadComplete") == true)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like firstly you need to fix onDownloadComplete method.

```
public void onDownloadComplete() {
    editor.putBoolean("downloadComplete", false);
    editor.apply();
    parseCSVFile(BASE_FILE_NAME);}
```

to

```
public void onDownloadComplete() {
    editor.putBoolean("downloadComplete", true);
    editor.apply();
    parseCSVFile(BASE_FILE_NAME);
}
```

Comment: actually I was testing true or false but nothing works, It still download the file just diff. is loading bar will not show percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Your onDownloadComplete() method does not put any value into the shared preference.
Replace your function with the below function:

```java
public void onDownloadComplete() {
    editor.putBoolean("downloadComplete", true);
    editor.apply();
    parseCSVFile(BASE_FILE_NAME);
}
```

Also in addition to this as you want to avoid downloading the file multiple time you need to check if the file has already been downloaded by checking if the the key is present in shared preferences. Change your onResume() method to below:

```java
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!sp.contains("downloadComplete")){

            downloadCSVFile(BASE_URL, BASE_FILE_NAME);
          }
    }
```

Retrieve the file otherwise if you need.

Comment: I tried your code, but it like screen stuck on point but still download the file in background and run forward after downloading app.

Comment: Change your commented if condition from: `if(sp.getBoolean("downloadComplete" == true))` to `if(sp.getBoolean("downloadComplete")==true)`

Comment: error: method getBoolean in interface SharedPreferences cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,boolean
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
@animeshk